# Bootanimation command not recognized without root

Tags: root-access, command-line, boot-animation

I am thoroughly confused. In a terminal, without root, when I run `bootanimation`, it says `/system/bin/sh: bootanimation: not found`. But when I am root, and run it, it works. Why is this? I attached a screenshot.[image: Here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because SELinux is enabled at the time.
Take a look at this. Let's pick `sh` as a comparison.
Note if you installed busybox then specify `toolbox ls` explicitly because SELinux-related functions in busybox is totally failing.

```
root@android:/system/bin # toolbox ls -Z bootanimation sh
-rwxr-xr-x root shell u:object_r:bootanim_exec:s0 bootanimation
-rwxr-xr-x root shell u:object_r:system_file:s0 sh
```

and...

```
u0_a0@android:/system/bin $ toolbox ls -Z bootanimation sh
ls: bootanimation: Permission denied
-rwxr-xr-x root shell u:object_r:system_file:s0 sh
```